# Get the calling field in a specialkey event handler

Tags: extjs

How can I take the source object in 'specialkey' event  in ExtJs?

This my controller code:

```
    init: function () {

            this.control({
                'login textfield[action=enter]': {
                    specialkey: this.on_KeyPress
                }
            });
        }

.......................
    on_KeyPress: function (f, e) {

        if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Keys', 'You pressed the Enter key');

*****I want to take 'textfield' object here*******

        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is doesn't work. The code :  var obj = e.getTarget() ; var win = obj.up('window'); ---error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-specialkey) show that the parameters passed to the `specialkey` are like so:

```
specialkey( Ext.form.field.Base this, Ext.EventObject e, Object eOpts )
```

So you can see that the first parameter is the field on which the event happend.

Thus, in your case:

```
console.log( f );
```

Would be the textfield object.